# loggly - how to exclude particular lines entry in loggly

Tags: php, logging, loggly

I have configured PHP log file to loggly. I can find there are too many entries for PHP notice i.e 3 out 4 is this php notice.

How can I exclude that particular log entries `PHP Notice:` in loggly? Alternative, can I exclude only php notice entries from php.ini file?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to exclude notice messages in your PHP configuration.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
```

Read more here http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php